# PHPWord - Wrapping text around a table

Tags: php, ms-word, docx, phpword

In PHPWord, is there a possibility to wrap text around a table? There is such setting in Word, but I could not find it among the available table style options.

Answer (score 0):

This is currently not implemented, there is an issue logged for it though (by you?): https://github.com/PHPOffice/PHPWord/issues/1093

Comment: Yes, that was me.